# Gradient Descent Numpy Linear Regression

Tags: numpy, linear-regression, gradient-descent

Hey I am trying to implement gradient descent in numpy for linear regression
My loss is:

```
def compute_square_loss(X, y, theta):

 size=len(y)
 y_estimate=X.dot(theta)
 y_estimate=np.array(y_estimate)
 y=np.array(y)

 error=y_estimate.flatten()-y.flatten()

 error=(1/size)*np.sum(error**2)
 return error
```

this is for the error and then for the gradient I try

```
def compute_square_loss_gradient(X, y, theta):

 error=compute_square_loss(X,y,theta)

 gradient = -(2.0/size) * np.dot(error,X)
 return gradient
```

This returns a array of length 1460(data size) and not 39(feature size). Can someone tell me how I can fix this? I am using MSE

Comment: From your question, it is unclear what is sample size and what is input dimension. What are the shapes of `X`, `y`, and `theta`?

Comment: In any case, you probably ought to weight by sample size (rather than `len(y)`), it's unclear why you flatten if the sample size is greater than one, you don't define `size` before using it in `compute_square_loss_gradient`, it is not clear why you use `np.dot`, when `error` is scalar (is that what you want)? Besides providing the shapes, you should also provide the actual issue that you are encountering.